# How to add menu item and content

Tags: custom-fields, menu

How do I add a new menu item (i.e. after the standard item Contacts, Members, Administration etc) and page which would contain a login to our mail. (Mail will display on this page (the new menu)).

Someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

in the menu->Administrater->Customize data and Screen->Navigation (civicrm/admin/menu), you can edit the menu and add entries

Comment: Ah that was kind of too easy. Is there documentation of what arguments you can add to the URL, if you want to change the behaviour (e.g. open an external page within the CiviCRM system)? The admin manual is silent on this as far as i can see.